# Volver a commit anterior

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

Trabajo en un branch llamado `master2`, el asunto es que hice pequeños cambios en 1 archivo y al intentar subirlos, cometi un error e hice `git pull origin master` y al hacer `push` me aparecieron casi todos los archivos del repositorio con conflicto, intente resolverlos pero no hubo caso. Necesito volver a la ultima version estable del repositorio o si es que se puede, revertir los cambios o eliminar los `commits`

**EDICION**

Hay 4 commits despues del que quisiera volver, se pudiera volver 4 commits antes?

Comment: si ya estas enfocado a ese commit solo has de realizar un `git reset --hard` y te descargara todo el contenido del commit

Comment: hice git checkout del commit, mi sistema funciona correctamente, ahora quiero subir el proyecto tal como esta, asi estable, por eso mi pregunta : 1) git checkout codigo_commit 2) revisar que todo funcione bien y 3) git push? esa es mi gran duda

Comment: no amigo, primero `git add .` despues `git commit -m "texto"` y por ultimo `git push origin nombre_de_la_rama` y crearas un commit por encima de los demas aunque tenga el mismo contenido

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Puedes volver a una revisión antigua usando `checkout` y pasando el hash del commit. Por ejemplo:

```
git checkout ab25f1ln2b4o3a9c4u1v6k4n1m7 .
```

No olvides el punto al final. También puedes descartar cambios mediante `reset` pasándole el numero de commits. Por ejemplo, para descartar los últimos 3 commits:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

La diferencia entre `checkout` y `reset` es que en éste último se **descartan** las revisiones, mientras que con `checkout` se preservan.

Comment: Excelente tu ayuda. Solo agregar que luego de volver a la version anterior hice el merge con el codigo del otro desarrollador y quedo todo actualizado.

Comment: Solicito ayuda por favor, en mi caso ya hice estos comandos pero el repositorio local me siguen quedando los archivos agregados recientemente... Quiero quitarlos para seguir trabajando. Les agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: ya no aceptan esta solucion de `HEAD~` `(fatal: argumento ambiguo 'HEAD~1': revisión desconocida o ruta fuera del árbol de trabajo.
Usa '--' para separar las rutas de las revisiones, de esta manera:
'git <comando> [<revisión>...] -- [<archivo>...])'`

Answer (score 9):

En tu caso seguramente no quieres mantener los cambios entonces :

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

O simplemente usa el id del commit:

```
git checkout <id commit>
```

Si deseas mantener los cambios y volver 4 commits antes:

```
git reset [--mixed] HEAD~3
```

Si sólo quieres mover el head a 4 cambios antes:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
```

Comment: al querer mantener los cambios (es un caso hipotetico) sabiendo que en el ultimo commit hay errores en mi sistema, como puedo discriminar los cambios? me refiero a como saber que cambios dejar y que cambios eliminar?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes volver al ultimo commit de la rama con `git reset --hard` (comprueba que estas en la rama correcta con `git status`).

Tambien puedes ver tus commits anteriores con `git log` y escoger uno de esos commits con `git checkout codigo_del_commit`.

Lamentablemente tendrás que buscar una versión estable de tu proyecto mediante antiguos commits, (git utiliza los commits como puntos de guardados).

*Si no guardas el juego y te matan, revives en el ultimo punto donde has guardado*

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, una consulta, tengo claro cual es el commit al que quiero volver. En este caso no me serviria git reset ya que el ultimo commit es erroneo. Al volver con `git checkout` y ver que esa funcion esta estable, puedo hacer commit para que el branch quede con esa version?

Comment: si, puedes hacer un `git commit -m "texto"` y hacer un commit por encima del erroneo

Comment: amigo muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda! +1 para ti

Answer (score 0):

para volver sin usar reset (descartando todo lo que has hecho en esos commits) usa

```
git revert el-hash-del-commit
```

o puedes usar

```
git revert HEAD
```

para regresar 1 commit desde el head a donde estas apuntando (tambien puedes usar HEAD~2)