# ¿Cómo ver los archivos modificados en local en git?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Tuve que cancelar un " git push" en medio de la operación. Ahora no encuentro listados los archivos que modifiqué como elegibles para ser subidos al repositorio remoto.

Si bien sigue estando en mi copia en local, no sé como seleccionar estos de nuevo para hacer un push nuevamente. Probé haciendo un fetch de nuevo, sin resultados aún.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al ejecutar el comando `git status` los archivos que se listan son aquellos que han sido modificados o que son nuevos en el repositorio.
El comando `git add [files]` guarda el estado de los archivos especificados.
Al ejecutar el comando `git commit -m"Mensaje de commit"` los cambios en estos archivos se registran en el historial de versiones. Por esta razón al ejecutar de nuevo el archivo `git status` estos archivos ya no aparecerán listados hasta que sean modificados.

---

Con respecto a la pregunta en tu comentario sobre regresar a una versión anterior.
Es posible ejecutando  alguno de los comandos.

> Puedes volver a una revisión antigua usando checkout y pasando el hash del commit. Por ejemplo:
>  `! git checkout ab25f1ln2b4o3a9c4u1v6k4n1m7 . !`
>  No olvides el punto al final. También puedes descartar cambios mediante reset pasándole el numero de commits. Por ejemplo, para descartar los últimos 3 commits:
>  `! git reset --hard HEAD~3 !`
>  La diferencia entre checkout y reset es que en éste último se descartan las revisiones, mientras que con checkout se preservan.
>
>  [Respuesta a "git - Volver a commit anterior"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/41497/156982)

## ¡Aviso!

Toma en cuenta que  al volver a una versión anterior perderás todos los cambios realizados, los archivos estarán tal cuál quedaron antes de que los modificaras e hicieras el actual commit. Y solo con la opción de `git checkout` es posible recuperar esos cambios.
Al interrumpir el proceso del comando `git push` los archivos de tu repositorio local no sufrieron ningún cambio y solo hace falta que corras de nuevo el comando `git push` para que tu repositorio remoto esté sincronizado con tu repositorio local.
Si hay algún problema con los archivos será en el repositorio remoto y al correr el comando `git push` te mostraría dichos problemas.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Exactamente esto fue lo que sucedió. ¿habría alguna forma de volver a un punto donde me listen los anteriores cambios sin realizar?

Comment: @alexmejia992 ya modifiqué mi respuesta para atender a tu pregunta. Por favor lee toda la información. Si tienes mas dudas estaré al pendiente.

Comment: un detalle al margen: `git push` no es una operación que afecte tu `árbol de trabajo`. Como estaba tu `árbol de trabajo` antes del push, es como se va a ver luego del push.... es decir, nada que pueda suceder en un push va a cambiar lo que pueda mostrar `git status` antes o después del mismo.