# Volver a un commit anterior con GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-desktop

En una pregunta anterior se explicaba como regresar a un commit anterior con una instrucción de Git.

[Volver a commit anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41489/volver-a-commit-anterior)

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna posibilidad de hacer lo mismo con GitHub Desktop

Comment: No uso GitHub Desktop, pero una búsqueda rápida parece indicar que no. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34791029/2437508

Comment: Esto te pdría ayudar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72033280/2437508

Comment: Es más, si funciona, podrías colocarlo como tu propia respuesta para que otras personas con la misma pregunta puedan ver una respuesta en español.

Comment: te recomiendo usar git y dejar de usar github pues git soporta completamnete github pero no a la inversa